# CSS for Graph DashBoard squishing fadein

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Essentially I am making a web program that fades in and fades out a bunch of graphs that I have for a graph dashboard (Using jQuery). The styling is all fine until the second set of graphs come in, essentially they all become squished to around 3 quarters the size.

Any help would be great.

CSS:

```
.header {
     height:8%;
     background:#F0F0F0;
     border:1px solid #CCC;
     background-color:#3f3f46;
     width:100%;
 }

 @font-face {
     font-family: 'Pricedown Bl';
     src: url('/font/pricedownbl.ttf');
 }

 .headerText {
     position:relative;
     text-align:center;
     color: green;
     font-family:"Pricedown Bl";
     letter-spacing: 2px;
 }

 html,body,.dashboard {
     position:absolute;
     width:100%;
     height:92%;
     margin:0;
 }

 .col1 {
     position:relative;
     float:left;
     width:25%;
     height:100%;
 }

 .col1 > div {
     position:relative;
     width:100%;
     height:29.75%;
 }

 img {
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="headerText">SDV PROC GRAPHS</div>
</div>

<div class="dashboard">
    <div class="col1">
        <div class="border"><img src=""></img></div>
        <div class="border"><img src="cuteimage"></img></div>
        <div class="border"><img src="cuteimage"></img></div>
        <div class="border"><img src="cuteimage"></img></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col1">
        <div class="border"><img src="cuteimage"></img></div>
        <div class="border"><img src="cuteimage"></img></div>
        <div class="border"><img src="cuteimage"></img></div>
        <div class="border"><img src="cuteimage"></img></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col1">
        <div class="border"><img src="cuteimage"></img></div>
        <div class="border"><img src="cuteimage"></img></div>
        <div class="border"><img src="cuteimage"></img></div>
        <div class="border"><img src="cuteimage"></img></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col1">
        <div class="border"><img src="cuteimage"></img></div>
        <div class="border"><img src="cuteimage"></img></div>
        <div class="border"><img src="cuteimage"></img></div>
        <div class="border"><img src="cuteimage"></img></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
setInterval ("fadeOUT()", 5000);
window.setTimeout("fadeIN()",6000);

function fadeOUT() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dashboard").fadeOut(2000);
})
}

function fadeIN() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dashboard2").fadeIn(3000);
    })
}
```